# Как подключить стороннюю библиотеку .dll к новому проекту в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, windows, dll, delphi-7

Здравствуйте, у меня есть библиотека написанная на Delphi 7, файл с расширением dll, и файл приложения для работы с этой библиотекой.

Задача стоит получить доступ к классам и методам которые описаны в библиотеке, необходимо внести изменения в программу исходников которой у меня нет, а её декомпилирование не дало положительных результатов.

Используя штатные средства среды разработки RAD 2010 либо Delphi 7, подключить эту библиотеку к новому проекту при использовании функции "Import Type Library" не получается, выводится "Ошибка при загрузке бибилотеки"(возможно я сделал что-то не правильно).

Есть ли иные варианты подключения библиотеки к проекту?

Comment: Скорее всего вы все сделали правильно, просто эта dll не является ActiveX library и не реализует COM-интерфейсы. Раз так, то доступ к функциональности этой библиотеки доступен вам только через экспортируемые функции. Доступа к классам и методам классов нет. И даже если бы был - нельзя обращаться к ним, поскольку (например) TForm в exe и TForm в dll - это **разные** классы с одним и тем же именем, отождествлять их опасно. При наличии описания экспортируемых методов обратите внимание, что PChar в D7 = PAnsiChar в D2009 и выше

Comment: Если сигнатур экспортируемых методов нет и нет доступа к исходникам (пусть не самой dll, а любого приложения, которое эту dll использует) - имхо, библиотеку можно выкинуть.